# Asp Net Core Dropdown com seleção dinâmica

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, dropdownlist

tenho a seguinte dúvida: supondo que eu tenho uma lista de cidades (asp-items=@(new selectList(model.cidades, "Id", "Name")). Como eu faria para listar as cidades de uma respectiva lista de UF (mesmo selectList de cidades mas usando o model de estados).

Tem como fazer isso em uma página razor ou teria que usar js por exemplo (se sim, como?).

Obrigado.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -3):

Só mesmo fazendo uma cascade drop down consigo ver uma solução em que selecionas a lista e na proxima drop down so teria as cidades dessa lista! (não conheço outra forma caso exista)

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).